# Turn multidimensional array into single array?

Tags: php, zend-framework, multidimensional-array, google-analytics

I'm trying to turn a multidimensional array created by iterating over an array created by a shopping cart:

```
Array (
    [array] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [product_id] => 7
            [prod_count] => 1
            [price] => 19.99
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [product_id] => 6
            [prod_count] => 3
            [price] => 19.99
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [product_id] => 5
            [prod_count] => 2
            [price] => 19.99
        )
        [3] => Array (
            [product_id] => 4
            [prod_count] => 4
            [price] => 14.99
        )
        [4] => Array (
            [product_id] => 3
            [prod_count] => 5
            [price] => 19.99
        )
    )
)
```

into something like this:

```
$items = array(
array('product_id'=> $val,  'price'=>$price, 'quantity'=>$prod_count),
array('product_id'=>$val, 'price'=>$price, 'quantity'=>$prod_count),
array('product_id'=>$val, 'price'=>$price, 'quantity'=>$prod_count)
);
```

So that I can feed it to the google analytics e-commmerce tracking code and echo the code below for each product in the array.

```
_gaq.push(['_addItem',
   '<?php $order_id; ?>',          // trans ID **I have this part figured out**
   '<?php $product_id; ?>',        // SKU/code - required
   '',                             // product name 
   '',                             // category or variation
   '<?php $price; ?>',             // unit price - required
   '<?php $prod_count; ?>'         // quantity - required
]);
```

Ive tried a bunch of solutions from SO but none of them seem to work right for my shopping cart array and honestly I'm stumped. Good people of SO please point me in the right direction.

EDIT* Here is my code that creates the multidimensional array in the first place.

```
$products = array();

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($productsIds); $i++){       
    $product = explode(":", $productsIds[$i]);
    $products[$i]['info'] = $this->Products->getProductById($product[0]);
    $products[$i]['count'] = $product[1];
    $products[$i]['price_count'] = $product[1]*$products[$i]['info']['product_price'];

    $orderarray[$i] = array(
        'product_id' => $products[$i]['info']['product_id'], 
        'prod_count' => $products[$i]['count'], 
        'price' => $products[$i]['info']['product_price']) ;
```

Maybe I could change this to create an array better suited for my desired outcome. Just not sure how.

Comment: You want us to create data out of thin air? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If there is anything I need to add please let me know and I will add it to the question.

Comment: For instance, where does `123DSW`, `Sandles` and `Footwear` values come from?

Comment: that was an example array form google analytics. Ive modified it to be more specific to my case. Sorry for the confusion. If I could even just get rid of the first dimension of the array I think I could foreach over it to make it work, the problem Im running into is array has to many dimensions.

Comment: So you want to flatten your array so that there's just one for each product?

Comment: Yes! and then echo the Google item tracking code once for each item. I think I can do this if I could remove the first dimension of the array. Maybe assign the first child array to a new variable then for each through it. Just not sure how to go about doing it. I've used nested for each statements but I can't echo the Google code correctly using that method. Any help is immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use your original array and pass them to gaq?:

```
// You could remove the need for [0] if you changed your original code
<?php foreach($yourOriginalArray[0] as $item) { ?>
  _gaq.push(['_addItem',
     '<?php $order_id; ?>',          // trans ID **I have this part figured out**
     '<?php echo $item['product_id']; ?>',        // SKU/code - required
     '',                             // product name 
     '',                             // category or variation
     '<?php echo $item['price']; ?>',             // unit price - required
     '<?php echo $item['quantity']; ?>'         // quantity - required
  ]);
<?php } ?>
```

The other data, product name and category, you will have to populate into your array as you have done with product_id, price, and quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Finally this worked

```
$ga_itemdata = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$ga_itemdata);

 foreach ($ga_itemdata as $gavar[0] => $details) {

echo "
_gaq.push(['_addItem',
    $order_id,
    $details[product_id],
    $details[prod_name],
    $none,
    $details[price],
    $details[prod_count]
    ]);
";
    }
```